# How do I expand each child element in a container on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box container with several child elements, each with the class .flex-item. My grid system is such that there are 3 flex items per row, each occupying 1/3 of the container width.

```
<div class="flex-box">

    <!-- start row 1 -->
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <!-- end row 1 -->

    <!-- start row 2 -->
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <div class="flex-item">[image and text]</div>
    <!-- end row 2 -->

</div>
```

**Desired functionality:**
On hover, I need each flex item to double its width, without moving any siblings.
** *For example*, if I hover over the first child item, it would completely cover up the second; the third flex item would stay put.
** *Similarly*, if I hover over the 5th flex item, it's width would expand to cover the 6th flex item, while all other flex items stay put.

**What I've tried:**
My first approach was purely CSS, using a combination of a) position: absolute, b) left/right offset, c) margin-left. But I ran into issues with consistently and accurately setting the margin-left property for the other siblings in the row. Also, this only worked well for the first row. With all other rows, I would need to calculate the top offset because I was using absolute positioning.

Is there a better, pure-CSS approach? If I should be using some JS/jquery in addition to CSS, how would I go about this?

Update: Here's a JSFiddle I created, showing desired functionality by using the first flex item as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4800pwru/

Comment: what happen if you hover the third item ?

Comment: Is the expectation that the content shifts to fill or are you just trying to scale your content?  Also, what does your CSS currently look like?  Consider setting up a JS Fiddle.

Comment: It would also double its width, except the third item would expand to the right, completely covering the second item.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that effect of scaling over the other elements, I guess a CSS-only approach with `position: absolute;` it's doable.

*OBS: I would just say that the problem to work with 3 columns and absolute positioning is the 33% width problem that eventually you'd have to decide how to fill the remaining 1% or do something about it.*

**Solution**

You'd have your child elements absolute positioned with `width: 33%;` and also the second child would be `left: 33%:` and so forth.

On hover you'd double the width to `66%` and chaneg the 'z-index' to a hight enough number.

Solving the third element hover growing outside the container you can change it's left to `33%`, that way it will grow over the middle element and the content will still be inside the parent element.

I've managed a working demo on this [jSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/ym2c952j/) that goes like this:

You'd have your normal HTML:

```
<ul class="container-box">
  <li class="container-box-item">Text</li>
  <li class="container-box-item">Text</li>
  <li class="container-box-item">Text</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS would be (using normalize.css & scss here):

```
ul.container-box {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


li.container-box-item {
  background-color: white;
  width: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    width: 66%;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  &:nth-child(n * 1) {
    left: 0;
    background-color:blue;
  }

  &:nth-child(n + 2) {
    left: 33%;
    background-color:green;
  }

  &:nth-child(n + 3) {
    left: 66%;
    background-color:yellow;
  }

  &:nth-child(n + 3):hover {
    left: 33%;
    background-color:yellow;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in mind, but accounts for only 3 child items. What would my approach be if I have one container and, say, 9 child items with a total of 3 rows?

Comment: @manh2244 do you need them to be inside the same parent? If not the ul elements can act like `rows` for the [elements inside](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/ym2c952j/2/)